# Display empty string if time is null - PHP/MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli, time

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
if(strtotime($row['time']) > "00:00:00") {
   $time = date('g:i A', strtotime($row['time']));
}  else{
   $time = '';
}
echo "<span class='infoTitle'>Time:</span> "."<span class='userInfo'>".$time."</span>"."<br>";
}
}
```

Hey guys, so i have the above code. What I'm trying to do is display an empty string where Time: is echoed. So if no time is input then this is what it should look like

```
Time:
```

If a time is input by the user, then it should display the time he input. For example if he puts in 6:00 PM.

```
Time: 6:00 PM
```

What the code is currently doing is displaying the correct time if a user inputs. But if left blank, then this displays:

```
Time: 12:00 AM
```

Any ideas whats going on here? Is 12:00 AM the default? If so, how do i tell PHP to leave it blank if its displaying that? Sorry guys, total PHP noob here. Barely 1 week into this. But its fun!

Answer (score 1):

12:00 AM is not default, but `strtotime()` returns FALSE on failure. False is equal to 0.

`date('g:i A',0)` would return 12:00 AM because it 's epoch time. 1970-01-01 00:00:00

To prevent this, you could run

```
if(strtotime($row['time'])>0){ 
   $time = date('g:i A', strtotime($row['time']));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it is still displaying 12:00 am. Any other approach that you would suggest?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of what you are putting into strotime?